# VFS package transmission and biometric fee

Tags: fees-and-charges, vfs-global

I submitted my visa application online and paid all fees including the one for biometric and I received the biometric letter as well. Now I need to give my biometrics to VFS. Can I make an appointment in package transmission? Will I need to pay the biometric fee again by using package transmission?

Comment: What country's visa are you applying for, and what country do you live/submit the application in? VFS services a lot of embassies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The clause "...can I taken appointment in package transmission?" is unclear. What are you asking here?